# Enlightenment needed to clear doubts on datetime vs smalldatetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, date, datetime-format

I have read up on this but still cannot understand. Hope someone here may explain it to me. I have a query that assigns a current date only value to my column. However I would like to know if I should create the new column as `DATETIME` or `SMALLDATETIME` if my query is like:

```
  Insert into table(col A)
  Select DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0) As ColA  
  from table B
```

I guess my select statement will already give me the date value without time. I am doubtful on the creation of `Col A` in my db table.  I am using Sql 2005.

Update:
So my qns is how to create my Column A in my db table? Do i need to add constraint to it? Which datatype is preferred?

Comment: You need to ask a specific and explicit question.  This is Question and Answer forum, not a discussion forum.

Comment: i am sorry if i am not specific enough, i will do an update. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: i added a CHECK constraint of (DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,CREATION_D),0)=CREATION_D) but does not work, what did i do wrong?

Comment: Re: your check constraint in the comments, "did not work" isn't a useful diagnostic. In what *way* did it not work? Error when you tried to apply it? Allowed values with time components? Disallowed values you expected to be allowed? Something else? - if so, maybe tell us what you *expected* it to do. If it's some kind of error, please edit your question and include the full script rather than a fragment.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server 2005 does not support the `date` data type.  That would be the data type that you really want.

The `smalldatetime` and `datetime` both store dates with a time component.  These are explained in the [SQL Server documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).  `Smalldatetime` is stored in four bytes and `datetime` is stored in 8 bytes.

For your purposes, they are probably equally useful.  The differences are the range that can be represented and the accuracy.  In both cases the accuracy is much less than one day, so either works for storing dates for most purposes.

Comment: ok thanks so you are saying both are equally useful for my case. So its ok for me to use either? So do i still need to include constraints while creating my column?

Comment: If you really want a constraint that says that there is no time component, then you can do that.  I tend to avoid constraints, putting the checks on the inputs rather than the table (and typically use store procedure interfaces for inserts and updates).